# NiFi's 'Run Mongo Aggregation' showing JSONMappingException: Unrecognized Token ISODate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, apache-nifi

Below is my sample data: (Parent JSON having floor information and every floor having multiple sensor information)

```
{"Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
    "name": "Forklifts",
    "Sensor_data": [{
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_002",
            "Asset_Id": 123,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996
        },
        {
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_003",
            "Asset_Id": 456,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996,
        },
        {
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_005 ",
            "Asset_Id": 127,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996
        },
        {
            "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
            "Floor_name": "Forklifts",
            "Name": "forkLift_001",
            "Asset_Id": 157,
            "Load": 1.7096133,
            "Timestamp": 1537878750996,
        }
]}
```

I want to calculate total load, total distance and active sensors for a floor. And the similar information (total load and total distance for every floor) on a per day basis. The desired response is like this:

```
{
    "TotalLoad": 3214,
    "Active_no_of_sensor":5,
    "Floor_Id": "Galileo_001",
    "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
    "AssetStatus": [{
        "TotalLoad": 200,
        "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
        "Date": "1539588994"
    }, {
        "TotalLoad": 400,
        "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
        "Date": "1539475200"
    }, {
        "TotalLoad": 100,
        "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
        "Date": "1539388800"
    }]
}
```

In NiFi, I am having two separate run mongo aggregation processors.

1. For calculating total load and total no of active sensors for every
   floor.
2. For calculating total load etc. for every floor per day basis.

For this 2nd condition, I'm using the below query:

```
[{"$unwind" : "$Sensor_data" },
{"$match": {"Floor_Id" : {"$eq": "${http.param.floorid}"}}},
{"$group": {
     "_id": {"Floor_Id": "$Floor_Id", 
         "DailyDate":{"$dateFromParts":{
                    "year":{"$year":{"$add": [ISODate("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]}},
                    "month":{"$month":{"$add": [ISODate("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]}},
                    "day":{"$dayOfMonth":{"$add": [ISODate("1970-01-01"), "$Sensor_data.Timestamp"]}}
                      } 
                  }
             },
     "AssetLoad": {"$sum": "$Sensor_data.Load" },
     "AssetDistance": {"$sum" : {"$subtract": [{"$toDecimal":"$Sensor_data.End_odometer"},
                                                {"$toDecimal":"$Sensor_data.Start_odometer"}]}}
    }
},
{
    "$group" : {
            "_id": {"Floor_Id": "$_id.Floor_Id"},
            "TotalLoad": { "$sum": "$AssetLoad" },
            "TotalDistance" : { "$sum": "$AssetDistance" },
            "AssetStatus":{
                "$push":{
                    "TotalLoad": "$AssetLoad",
                    "LoadUnit": "Kgs",
                    "TotalDistance" : "$AssetDistance",
                    "Date": "$_id.DailyDate"
                    }
                }
        }
},
{"$project" : {
    _id:0,
    "AssetStatus" : 1

    }
}]
```

**Error**

The processor shows `'Error running mongodb aggregation query: Unrecognized Token ISODate: was expecting null, true, false or NaN'`

How can I resolve this issue? (I do not want to update the format of date from BSON Long to ISODate in the collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED**

Replaced ISODate with $convert operator in Run Mongo Aggregation processor

Comment: Can you post your solution? I am using Mongo 3.4 and there is no convert operator in there.

Answer (score 0):

The ISODate function does not work on the `RunMongoAggregation` and `GetMongo` processor. You should use the following phrase instead and it should be in json :

```
   { 
        "createdAt" : { 
            "$gte" : {"$date": "2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
        }
    }
```